# Understanding .NET configuration file scheme

Tags: .net, app-config, configuration-files

I have some difficulties with configuration files in .Net: I completely understand its essence and what are they good for, but the part I miss is this: configuration file is xml file that in runtime deserializes to managed object (or OBJECTS???) on the managed heap. But who are those objects?

To clarify my question, I will give one concrete example:
If I write a WCF service, I can configure my service using the **System.serviceModel** element.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <!-- and this is wherer the service configuration goes... -->
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Now, how can I access this object using via code? what is the the object's name and type? I was thinking about ConfigurationManager - but its not there.

btw, if you wondering, the reason why I find this question so relevant is this: If I knew the scheme of the configuration file, I would know how to exploit it the best...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root element corresponds to the [`Configuration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration.aspx) class and deserializes to it.

It contains many different other possible elements and some customisable sections, normally with the [`ConfigurationSection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsection.aspx) class which one can subclass from and use.

The `system.serviceModel` section is just one such section - you can find more information on the element itself [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731354.aspx) and about the object it deserializes to - [`ServiceModelConfigurationGroup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.configuration.servicemodelsectiongroup.aspx).

The [`ConfigurationManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) is a static class that provides access to the deserialized configuration (for example, you can get a configuration section by using the [`GetSection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.getsection.aspx) method).

Comment: thanks for the answer. I still have some questions: what types inherit from ConfigurationSection? and how can I know that system.serviceModel section deserializes to ServiceModelConfigurationGroup type? Its not that I dont believe you, its just that there are other sections I would like to know about in the future :)

Comment: @ET - Go to the MSDN page and click the `more...` link under "Inheritance Hierarchy" to see what inherits from it. You can also write custom ones that will not be listed on MSDN. As for being sure... Look at the documentation for the configuration element linked above.

Comment: I know how to see the derived types, but I cant find ServiceModel between them. What i ment to ask is this - what is the type that derive from ConfigurationSection that fits to the System.ServiceModel section?

Comment: @ET - If you look at the documentation, you will see that the class and the element documentation agree (have same named properties and same types). The config section will be registered somewhere - possibly in the machine wide web config (which will have the type as well), though it might be baked into the runtime, in which case I don't know how to prove it...

Answer (score 1):

All the configuration sections are handled by "configuration section handlers". All of these need to be specified in the `<configSections>` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228256.aspx element of the config file. If they are not defined there, they have already been defined in the machine.config or the global web.config file.

You can find `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` as a class in the `System.Configuration` DLL, which is part of the .NET framework (it's a bit confusing, because some of the System.Configuration namespace is already declared in the `System` DLL, but to get the `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager`, you need to reference the `System.Configuration.dll`.